# Transforming from 2D uniform to piecewise uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

P is a 2D uniform distribution with density $p(x,y)=\chi_{[0,1]^2}$,

Q is a 4-piecewise-uniform distribution with density

$\begin{equation}
q(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2} &  & (x,y)&\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]^2 \\
2 &  & (x,y)&\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]\times(\frac{1}{2},1] \\
1&  & (x,y)&\in(\frac{1}{2},1]\times[0,\frac{1}{2}] \\
\frac{1}{2} &  & (x,y)&\in(\frac{1}{2},1]^2 \\
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}$

I am thinking about using a continuos mapping to get Q from P. Is it possible to do that?
I know we can use inverse of cdf to do so in 1D, but it seems cannot generalize this method to 2D cases.

Comment: You could find the marginal distribution for $x$ (still a continuous distribution) and then use your inverse CDF method on that

Comment: Do you mean that decomposing the density to be the product of p(x) and p(y|x) and then use inverse CDF twice? it seems not to be a continuos map.

Comment: That is caused by your density function $q(x,y)$ being discontinuous at both $x=\frac12$ and $y=\frac12$